What is the difference between 3 separate 5x5x1 convolutions, and one 5x5x3 convolution?
The actual numbers are just for the sake of clarifying my question, of course. What I mean is, since each channel in a multi-channel convolution has its own filter, what difference does it make if, given three 2d-arrays of data, one first combines that into a multi-channel input that undergoes a multi-channel convolution, vs. use three separate one channel convolutions?
The "channels" just seem to exist for organizing related inputs conceptually rather than mathematically changing anything. Am I missing something?

There is a difference. The output of a "multi-channel convolution" (e.g. 5x5x3) can potentially combine information across channels. For example, it can compute the sum or difference of two channels. This is not possible using a per-channel convolution.
